# Why clicking the button is not giving a valid text in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 `cards` like the below.

```
  <div class="card" id="b1">
          <div class="card-header">
               <div class="card-title">
                 Sample card 1
               </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
             <div class = "content1"> </div>
             <div class = "content2"> </div>
             <div class = "content3"> </div>
          </div>
          <button class="button1">0</button>
      </div>

      <!-- card 2 -->
  <div class="card" id="b2">
          <div class="card-header">
               <div class="card-title">
                 Sample card 1
               </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
             <div class = "content1"> </div>
             <div class = "content2"> </div>
             <div class = "content3"> </div>
          </div>
          <button class="button1">0</button>
      </div>
```

Js :

```
var btnVal = [];
function buttonData(card.id) {
    btnVal[card.id] = ! btnVal[card.id] ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1;
   switch(btnVal[card.id]) 
    {
     case 0:
      return {
       target: card.id,
       content1 : "Nice to code using Js",
       };
     case 1:
      return {
       target: card.id,
       content2 : "Nice to code using JQuery",
       };
      case 2:
       return {
       target: card.id,
       content1 : "Hello",
       content2 : "Greetings",
       };
       default:
         return {};
       }
  } 

function toaddtheText(card) {
    Callback(buttonData(card) , function (data) {
      bodyText(data)
    });
  }
 
function bodyText(data) {

if(data.content1) 
{
 var target = document.getElementById(data.target);
 var content = target.getElementsByClassName('content1')[0];
 content.innerHTML = data.content1;
}

if(data.content2) 
{
 var target = document.getElementById(data.target);
 var content = target.getElementsByClassName('content2')[0];
 content.innerHTML = data.content2;
}
 }
   
 $(document).on("click", ".button", function () {
   buttonData(b1);
});
```

When I click the `button` in a specific card  for the first time, `case 0` should be implemented, the next time, `case1`  and the next time `case2` should be implemented.

But, If I click the button, it directly takes the `case2` and not the `case1`.

The problem is, the `data` is taking only the `content2` text for all the targets. The `content1` text  is **ignored**.

`console.log(data) gives the following result`.

```
object {
target: b1,
content2: "Nice to code using JQuery",
},
object {
target: b2,
content2: "Nice to code using JQuery",
},
```

Could someone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: You went too far obfuscating your actual use case, so your html and javascript seem to mismatch. If you post executable snippet reproducing your problem, you're much likely to get some help.

Comment: In `buttonData(b1)`, what is `b1`? There's an element with that ID, but no variable. You're also calling `Callback`, but the function doesn't exist. Please create a proper [mre]. Also keep in mind that using spaces in order to create readable code is great but HTML is an exception. The browser will probably parse `<div class = "content1"> </div>` as `<div class="content1"> </div>` but that is not guaranteed in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line of the `buttonData` function changes the value of `btnVal[card.id]` to `1` if the value is `0`, so you never get the first case:

```
btnVal[card.id] = ! btnVal[card.id] ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1;
```

In the above, your first ternary says if `btnVal[card.id]` is falsey (which `0` is) the set `btnVal[card.id]` to `1`. After that you go through your switch case with `btnVal[card.id] = 1`.

Assuming that you're not expecting other falsey values, you can either remove this ternary completely, or else have `btnVal[card.id] !== undefined` rather than `!btnVal[card.id]`.

[EDIT] You can replace the above line with:

```
btnVal[card.id] = btnVal[card.id] !== undefined ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1;
```

Or, if you are sure the functionality is correct then put this line at the end of the function, so you are only changing the value after you use it.

The full function then becomes:

```
function buttonData(card.id) {
  // store the current value of the card id if it exists, or zero.
  const value = btnVal[card.id] || 0;
  // increase the btnVal number 
  btnVal[card.id] = value > 1 ? 0 : value + 1;
  switch(btnVal[card.id]) {
    case 0:
      return {
        target: card.id,
        content1 : "Nice to code using Js",
      };
    case 1:
      return {
        target: card.id,
        content2 : "Nice to code using JQuery",
      };
    case 2:
      return {
        target: card.id,
        content1 : "Hello",
        content2 : "Greetings",
      };
    default:
      return {};
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since, btnValue = [] is empty. I used the ternary. btnVal[card.id] = ! btnVal[card.id] ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1; But, `It didn't work. `. Could you please give some suggestions to work  other than using ternary? . Many thanks. @Tom

Comment: You don't need to remove your ternary. If you're sure that it will always be an array, instead of having:
`btnVal[card.id] = ! btnVal[card.id] ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1;`
you can use
`btnVal[card.id] = btnVal[card.id] !== undefined ? 1 : btnVal[card.id] == 2 ? 0 : btnVal[card.id] + 1;`

Comment: @ Tom, The ternary, Which I used, Skips the cases. I need to execute each and every case.  If i use d
  `
    btnValue[card.id] = typeof (btnValue[card.id]) == 'undefined'
      ? 0
      : btnValue[card.id] === 3 ? 0 : btnValue[card.id] + 1; ` Which executes `case1 first, skips case2 and executes case3`. Why, I couldn't get the continous execution of cases. Could you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: @Davi What I'd do is have a simple validation before running your switch. Something like `const value = btnVal[card.id] || 0;`

Then after your switch case you KNOW that `value` is a number, and you can just do `btnVal[card.id] = value + 1;`

Comment: var value = btnValue[card.id] || 0;
    btnValue[card.id] = typeof (btnValue[card.id]) == 'undefined'
      ? 0
      : btnValue[card.id] === 3
      ? 0
      : value + 1; You mean, like the above. But, that too skips the `case2`.

Comment: @Davi see the latest edit at the bottom of my answer. create a new variable that is either the btnVal entry or 0. Then we update btnVal to that value + 1 but we're using value still in the function