# Why switching does not works on each button click in Js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `button`, in each card. The button, When I click for the first time should give a **text**  for the second time should give a particular text and for the third time the same. The order of the click should be `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3 ...`

I have an empty array, since the button Value is not known. Like the below,

```js
 var btn = [];
 function btnVal(ele) {
 btn[ele.id] = !btn[ele.id] ? 1 : btn[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : btn[ele.id] +1;
 switch(btn[ele.id])
 {
  case 0:
  return {};
  case 1 :
  return {};
  case 2 :
  return {};
  case 3:
   return {};
  default:
   }
 }
```

```html
 <button id = "button1"></button>
```

The ternary

```
btn[ele.id] = !btn[ele.id] ? 1 : btn[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : btn[ele.id] +1;
```

*It didn't work!*

The problem, When I click the button, It always takes the `case3` value. All the other cases were ignored.

**I need to execute each and every case.**

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @Liam, The ternary operator is not working!

Comment: Now is a great time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Using the script debugger you can place breakpoints in the code to pause execution and step through the execution line by line, observing the exact runtime behaviors and exact runtime values of your variables/objects/etc.  When you do this, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What are the exact runtime values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1qje8do0/2/

Comment: Given that your ternary seems to be a cut and paste of [another answer you've received](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69658168/542251). I'd suggest you take the time to understand the code and to debug the problem rather than just asking someone to fix it (whatever it is) for you.

Comment: @Jabaa, not sure, Why it takes the values from the case 3 for me. When I Click the button the order is `3, 0 ,1 , 2, 3, 0, ...`

Comment: In your question: _"The problem, When I click the button, It always takes the case3 value. All the other cases were ignored."_ In your comment: _"When I Click the button the order is `3, 0 ,1 , 2, 3, 0, ...`"_ Please elaborate. The problem is unclear for me. In my jsfiddle it starts with 1. The order is: 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... If the behavior of your actual code is different than the behavior of your [mcve], you should fix your example to reproduce the problem. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Jabaa, I used `console.log(btn[ele.id]) `to check, the value's order. When I press the button for the first time, it took the Value 3 and the second time Value 0 the third time 1 . Like that 3, 0 ,1,2 ,3 .. and it takes the Text which is under the `case 3` all the other text were ignored.

Comment: @Jabaa, the order should be 0, 1, 2, 3 ,0 ,1 ,2, 3 ..

Comment: In that case your [mcve] doesn't reproduce your actual problem: https://imgur.com/a/8NlyO5o It clearly starts with 1 and not with 3

Comment: @Jabaa, to start with zero, do I need to use` btn[ele.id] = !btn[ele.id] ? 0 : btn[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : btn[ele.id] +1;`

Comment: @Jabaa, Do you mean to  use the line after switch? I used `btn[ele.id] = !btn[ele.id] ? 0 : btn[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : btn[ele.id] +1;` It didn't work too!

Comment: I've posted an answer with a working code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the assignment to the end and add a new case for `undefined`:

```js
var btn = [];

function btnVal(ele) {
  switch (btn[ele.id]) {
    case 0:
    case undefined:
      console.log('case 0');
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log('case 1');
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log('case 2');
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log('case 3');
      break;
    default:
  }
  btn[ele.id] = !btn[ele.id] ? 1 : btn[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : btn[ele.id] + 1;
  return {};
}

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', btnVal);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. But how about storing current button counter in dataset of each button and picking appropriate text from an array

```
    <button class="btn" data-counter="0">Some text</button>
    <button class="btn" data-counter="0">Some text</button>
    <button class="btn" data-counter="0">Some text</button>

    <script>
        var texts = ["Some text", "Text1", "Text2", "Text3"];

        document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function (){
                this.dataset.counter = +this.dataset.counter + 1;
                
                if(this.dataset.counter % 4 == 0){
                    this.dataset.counter = 0;
                }

                this.innerText = texts[this.dataset.counter];
            });
        });
    </script>
```